# Refactor Java enum into a core project which does not contain classes that the enum points at

Tags: java, enums

I have 2 Java projects, `core-project` and `component-project`.

`core-project` is a dependency to `component-project`.

`component-project` originally contained an `Enum` e.g:

```
public enum ResourceType {

  APP("app", "App", App.class),

  WORKSPACE("ws", "Workspace", Workspace.class);

  private String extension;

  private String description;

  private Class<?> klass;

  ResourceType(final String extension, final String description, final Class<?> klass) {
    this.extension = extension;
    this.description = description;
    this.klass = klass;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I now need to move `ResourceType` down into `core-project` but I cannot move `Workspace.class` down into `core-project`, it must remain in `component-project`.

What would be an elegant approach to refactor this `Enum` into `core-project`?

Comment: Remove the `Class<?>` param from it? In `component-project`, you could have `switch (resourceType) case APP -> App.class ...` somewhere, or it could even have its own `ClassAwareResourceType` enum with `ResourceType type, Class<?> klass`.

Comment: I think you should go a step back. **Why do you need to move the `ResourceType`?** If it has this kind of hard dependency on classes from the component-project, I would argue it is quite possible it belongs there. Maybe it would help if you elaborated about what is the meaning of the `ResourceType`.

Comment: @sp00m "Remove the `Class<?>` param from it?" That is needed to link the `extension` to a handler class. Not sure what you mean by `ClassAwareResourceType` ..

Comment: If you want to have the Class in the enum then you will have to establish a dependency in core-project back to component-project - which creates a circular dependency - BAD.  You could  hide this by recording the fully-qualified Class name and forcing consumers to load the Class themselves - this makes it a hidden dependency - WORSE.  Maybe this enum is doing too much - maybe the element-to-Class mapping should be refactored out to some utility in component-project.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos It needs to be moved so that it can be accessed by other parts of `core-project` now, which was previously not the case. `App.java` will move alongside `ResourceType.java` .. however `Workspace.java` will not move as it is not part of `core-project`

Comment: OK - can you explain what is the purpose of the `ResourceType`? How is it intended to be used? Why does it need to reference the other classes?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos `ResourceType` basically maps XML file types to their POJO representations. There is a deserialization util class inside `core-project` which unmarshalls the XML to their POJO representations e.g `deserializer.unmarshall(ResourceType.Workspace)`

Answer (score 0):

One (not too elegant) way could be something like

```
public enum ResourceType {

    APP("app", "App", "com.example.App"),

    WORKSPACE("ws", "Workspace", "com.example.Workspace");

    private String extension;

    private String description;

    private Class<?> klass;

    ResourceType(final String extension, final String description, final String klass) {
        this.extension = extension;
        this.description = description;
        try {
            this.klass = Class.forName(klass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.klass = null;
        }
    }
}
```

With the expectation of some NPEs when the classes aren't present...